# Insert File from Microsoft Teams

Tags: vba, ms-word, microsoft-teams

I have a little problem with VBA. I wrote for my work an macro which starts at opening a Word file and builds an instruction from different parts.
It works like this:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()


ThisDocument.Activate

Selection.Delete

Selection.InsertNewPage

Selection.InsertFile ("G:\08.Erstinbetriebnahme\Maschinen Mittelschicht\Anleitung\01_Abschnitte\25_Elektrik_vorbereiten(EVC).docx")
Selection.InsertNewPage
Selection.InsertFile ("G:\08.Erstinbetriebnahme\Maschinen Mittelschicht\Anleitung\01_Abschnitte\30_Medienversorgung_und_Spannungen_prüfen.docx")
Selection.InsertFile ("G:\08.Erstinbetriebnahme\Maschinen Mittelschicht\Anleitung\01_Abschnitte\40_2021-02-24_Einleseprozess Erstinbetriebnahme.docx")
Selection.InsertNewPage

and so on...
```

The problem is, that not everyone who needs this instructions has the permission from the IT for the folder where the files from the instruction are.

Now I wanted to make it from Microsoft Teams, because there we can add the members who need it by ourself, but when I change the directories it looks like this

```
Selection.InsertFile ("https://engelglobal.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/0833-Anleitung/Shared%20Documents/Anleitung/Anleitung/01_Abschnitte/~$rbereitung%20allgemein%20(f%C3%BCr%20alle%20Maschinentypen).docx")
Selection.InsertNewPage
Selection.InsertFile ("https://engelglobal.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/0833-Anleitung/Shared%20Documents/Anleitung/Anleitung/01_Abschnitte/15_Elektrik_vorbereiten(Allgemein).docx")
```

and I got an error message.

Does anybody know how I can add files from Teams?